# How to compose proper insert/update/delete commands to update linked tables in source access database?

Tags: c#, database, oledb, ole, oledbcommand

I have to use MS Access.

I have database with this structure (don't mind strange names - it barely translated for this question):

[image: enter image description]

My program display one of this tables (in WinForms). User can change data in it. To send changed data I use button.

Here is problem. If I use OleDbCommandBuilder to generate commands I get error after pressing save button (if something was changed in table).

So, if I change something in desease table: DataTable "table" does not include DataColumn "patient ID" for this SourceColumn "patient ID" (error text is translated so may look a bit different).

If I change something in visits table: syntax error INSERT INTO. And so on about UPDATE and DELETE.

Looks like I have to compose commands manually. But I don't get how to do it. MSDN example don't really help.

So, please, help me to compose right commands for tables "visits" and "desease". Or at least discribe how to compose it.

In case if something is not clear without code of my form:

```
protected string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
protected OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
protected OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
protected OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder;

DataSet dataSet;

public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    connection.ConnectionString = conStr;
    adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", connection);
    dataSet = new DataSet();
    cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

    connection.Open();
    adapter.UpdateCommand = cBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
    adapter.InsertCommand = cBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
    adapter.DeleteCommand = cBuilder.GetDeleteCommand(true);
    connection.Close();
}

private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    adapter.Update(dataSet); //this method send data to database and return error
}
```

Guess, load code is not needed.

Comment: so what is the problem/error with the code you show at the end?

Comment: @hoijui, basically, it's fine. I just have to manually compose `adapter.UpdateCommand`, `adapter.InsertCommand` and `adapter.DeleteCommand`. I thought withous this code something may be unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This idea is probably mistake. Better to look for some alternative for MS Access.